# Change column indices based on mean of the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two input text files, TestA.txt and TestB.txt. The files are as follows:

```
TestA.txt
ABA     50000   2.3
BAA     75000   1.75
BBA     100000  2
TEST    100000  2.4

TestB.txt
ABA     2.3     50000
BAA     1.75    75000
BBA     2       100000
TEST    2.4     100000
```

When I try to pass each of these files one by one, it works just fine with my code below. However, when I pass both files in, it jumps to the else case.

I have attempted to write an if else case to account for this but for some reason if the files are not passed in individually, it just jumps to the else case instead of the elif.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
folder = Path("C:\\Users\\Project")
for f in folder.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(f) as fin:
        chk_lst = next(fin).split()
    is_h = not any(v[0].isdecimal() for v in chk_lst)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=(0, 1)[is_h])], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

ticker = df[0].str.split()    
mean1 = df[1].mean()
mean2 = df[2].mean()

pct_change = (100 * (mean2 - mean1)/mean1)
pct_change_flip = (100 * (mean1 - mean2)/mean2)
# print(pct_change)

if mean2 > mean1 and abs(pct_change_flip) > 95:
    df = df[[0, 2, 1]]
    df.columns = ['Identifier', 'Quantity', 'Rate']
    print(df)
elif mean1 > mean2 and abs(pct_change) > 95:
    df.columns = ['Identifier', 'Quantity', 'Rate']
    print(df)

else:
    print("Please conduct manual check of data.")
```

My goal is to try to flip the index of all files coming in to look like TestA.txt. Which means, all output should have the identifier in the first column, the large quantity value in the second and the small rate value in the third.

Final case should look like

```
Identifier  Quantity    Rate
ABA         50000       2.3
BAA         75000       1.75
BBA         100000      2
TEST        100000      2.4
Identifier  Quantity    Rate
ABA         50000       2.3
BAA         75000       1.75
BBA         100000      2
TEST        100000      2.4
```

Comment: Index is bit misleading word here. Did you mean to set a fixed arrangement of columns for all the files?

Comment: What do you mean by passing both files at the same time? Is the above code a function? How do you call it when you process both files? Show the complete code.

Comment: Passing both files at the same time simply means reading both files instead of just one of the files. The reordering should only happen if the mean calculation of the column makes sense. Basically, quantity should always be greater than rate. Some files have the quantity and rate column flipped so I just want to make sure that all outputs look like Identifier then Quantity then Rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas`'s `loc` function to pre-set the column indices before processing anything.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'z':['apple', 'bob', 'cat']})
df.loc[:,['y', 'x', 'z']]
# Do something
```

Comment: the goal is not to preset. I am trying to determine the column indices based on the mean of the column. If the mean of the second column is greater than the third, it stays. If the mean of the second column is less than the third column, we flip them.

Comment: Use `df.loc[:,['y', 'x', 'z']]` in your if-else block. You don't need to do this

`df = df[[0, 2, 1]]
    df.columns = ['Identifier', 'Quantity', 'Rate']`

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to work. it goes straight to my else case regardless of the fact that it should print out of the if and elif